# How can I find an element with maximum index using selenium-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate the element with the help of index.

Currently I'm using below `xpath` to identify by providing matching index value.
`//table/tbody/tr[@index='1']`

How can I locate element which is having maximum index value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. I don't think there is a xpath for directly finding the highest value.

```
trs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr")
max = 0
i = 0
for index, tr in enumerate(trs):
    if max < int(tr.get_attribute('index')):
        max = int(tr.get_attribute('index'))
        i = index

max = trs[i]

# If there are more than one elements with the same max value
maxs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr[@index='" + str(max) + "']")
```

Comment: @ Jason Estibeiro: I tried with above code. I got error. Then I slightly modified it. It is working. Thank you.

Comment: @TesterP - I forgot to enumerate `trs`. I've edited the answer. Do check this once again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in `max` function, specifying the `key` argument as a function that retrieves the `index` attribute.

```
# Setup
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://example.com')
rows = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr")

# Solution
max_element = max(rows, key=lambda e: e.get_attribute('index'))
```

If that `lambda` looks a little confusing, you can break it out into a plain function:

```
def get_index(element): return element.get_attribute('index')
max_element = max(rows, key=get_index)
```

If you need multiple maximums, I would call `get_attribute` on each and pass that to `max` in order to get the maximum `index` and then loop through the list again to get the maximum:

```
max_index = max(e.get_attribute('index') for e in rows)
max_elements = [e for e in rows if e.get_attribute('index') == max_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Below code worked for me:

trs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr")
    max = 0
    i = 1
    for tr in trs:
        if max < int(tr.get_attribute('index')):
            max = int(tr.get_attribute('index'))
            i = max                
    print (str(i))
```